# Private IP is disclosure at HTML when 302 status code is found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nginx, https, weblogic

I have J2EE web application ,  I using web server for nginx and app server for weblogic. The problem is Private IP for example 111.11.11.111:7001 was disclosed when status code 302 redirect is found then it showing the following response:

```
<html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
<p>It's now at <a href="https://myserverurlname.com">http://111.11.11.111:7001/myserverurlname.com</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

So how can i remove that private IP from inside html tag? Is there a way to override that HTML?Is there a way to set up inside backend code or serverside like nginx ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `ngx_http_sub_module` for that

```
location / {
    sub_filter 'http://111.11.11.111:7001'  'https://myserverurlname.com';
    sub_filter_once on;
}
```

Please take a look into the documentation for a detail explanation of the module
[ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)